# WKSwipeGestureRecognizer not working in cell of WKInterfaceTable

Tags: watchkit

I'd like to get swipes on certain cells within a WKInterfaceTable.
It is possible to add a `WKSwipeGestureRecognizer` to a group within a cell but the action is never called.

Adding the recognizer to the table works but this way I cannot get a reference to the cell that was tapped.

Any ideas/ or solutions to this issue?